# ion-select component of Ionic 3 not working in IOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios9, ionic3

We have developed one application using Ionic 3. We have used ion-select component at multiple places. In android & IOS version > 10, everything is working fine as expected.

But In IOS 9, ion-select component breaks. It shows blank options when tapping on ion-select.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
   <ion-select>
     <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
     <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Result:

[image: Error image on physical device]

Environment Details:

Specific IOS version in which issue is reproducible: 9.3.5

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2 ios 4.2.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.7.1-201710060319
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.8.0
OS         : OS X El Capitan
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
npm        : 4.2.0
```

Comment: I just tested, it works for me, are you sure you have not set css that override ion-option or some classes associated with it ? To be sure, try a blank project and just put your selector and you will see if it's your css or ionic

Comment: Actually I tried to remove all the classes and css but issue was present. Let me try with a blank project now.

Comment: OK test that to be sure

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: You are using a nightly version of ionic-angular with an old version of `app-scripts` and an old CLI version, thats probably the problem.

Comment: Hi, My info is as following . can anyone let me know bez I am also facing this issue .

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    Node       : v8.9.1
    npm        : 5.2.0 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading the app-scripts version to 2.1.4 from 3.0.1.

I also had to add dev dependency tsc-wrapped to resolve some ts lint issues.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
},
```

After changing my configuration to above, the webpack process duration came down to 3-4 minutes from 35 minutes.